# Convert an argument passed to an npm script to an environment variable

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

This is my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "bash do_something.sh && jest",
  "...": "..."
}
```

In my package, there is the `package.json` and `do_something.sh` files at the package root, and a `test_file.spec.ts` module in `./src`.

So doing `npm run start` from the CLI first runs the shell script with bash, then when the shell script finishes, it runs jest. This works fine so far.

However, there is a hardcoded constant, say `FOO`, inside `do_something.sh` (as `FOO="bar"`) and inside the test module (as `const FOO = "bar";`). Instead of having to change the constant in both files upon each run, I would like to be able to set it from the CLI when calling the script, by doing something like:

`npm run start --FOO=bar`

I would then want to intercept that CLI argument from within the npm script definition in the `package.json`, and set it as an environment variable accessible within the `do_something.sh` shell script, and within the `test_file.spec.ts` module.

So in the `package.json` I would do something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "env FOO=$npm_config_FOO bash do_something.sh && jest",
  "...": "..."
}
```

(I am using the `npm_config_` approach from [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/npm-scripts))

Then from within `do_something.sh`:

```
echo $FOO
```

And within `test_file.spec.ts`:

```
console.log(process.env.FOO);
```

I think I am close to getting it working, just a few missing steps I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's very close to what you have

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "export FOO=\"$npm_config_FOO\"; bash do_something.sh && jest"
   ...
}
```

which is going to export `FOO` and it will be available in `bash` and `jest` environments.

Comment: This looks good, although it has the downside of not being platform independent.